# Discord Oauth2 API request return empty query param

Tags: next.js, discord, aws-amplify

I am implementing discord oauth2 in nextjs and I am having a problem when I deploy to amplify, it works fine in my localhost but it fails in production, my implementation looks like this in the profile page for someone to link their discord account

```js
    <a className="text-indigo-800" href={`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${NEXT_PUBLIC_DISCORD_API_ID}&redirect_uri=${NEXT_PUBLIC_DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&scope=identify`}>
    {" "}{userData.discordUsername || 'Link account'}
    </a>
```

this creates a link that someone can click and they are taken to discord to authenticate, till there everything seem ok, the problem comes now when discord redirects to `/api/verify-acount`

which looks like this

```js
    const discordLink = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
      console.log("query", req.query);
    }
```

as you can see I ended up knowing the error was here coz I logged req.query which return an object in localhost with the code for user `query { code: 'somecode' }` but in amplify after going to couldwatch to see the logs then the object is empty

[image]

this ends up messing up everything from there as the code is not available to verify and get user details to store in the database.

what I don't know is exactly what caused this error.

I hope someone has idea and will be willing to help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was actually weird and I still don't understand why it had to happen

but my redirect domain was `https://subdomain.domain.zyx` which amplify accepts and redirects requests to `https://www.subdomain.domain.zyx` which is the accepted link in the browser (users will always see this even if they enter the first URL) coz of the explained scenario (no www prefix for one of them)

so I was requesting to link discord from `https://www.subdomain.domain.zyx` and discord would redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.zyx` and AWS would redirect to `https://www.subdomain.domain.zyx` so what I still don't understand is where the query params got lost in these steps but after changing redirect URL in discord to `https://www.subdomain.domain.zyx` then everything works fine now